# How to take out or change Key name of array-like object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, nested-loops

I need to calculate the average scores per sub-array in **javascript** .. To do that i'm aiming to do a double loop for array[i][j].. but the problem is  the key name or index per each sub-array is above 18k so my loop goes full overflow!!

by "my loop goes full overflow". I mean:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]) 
 };

 /*
   will log =>> nothing stack overflow, stop your code before you start  
   to smell smoke 
 */
```

To do that i need to the change the key name or to take it out, but i don't know how.
Any hint?? or guideline ??

Thanks

small example bellow of my inputs (i have for 1 user 4000 inputs more or less):

##### Current data :

i don't know how to represent it!!

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

I don't know how to represent the structure showed in the images... is something like these

```
 const results = 
 {
   "18456": [
            {id: 1767, data: "blabla", score: 50, date:'2022-08-02T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1766, data: "blabla", score: 70, date: '2022-08-02T12:24:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1765, data: "blabla", score: 68, date: '2022-08-02T12:23:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1764, data: "blabla", score: 13, date: '2022-08-02T12:22:00.000Z'}
          ],
   "19212": [
            {id: 1763, data: "blabla", score: 20, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1762, data: "blabla", score: 75, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1761, data: "blabla", score: 80, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1760, data: "blabla", score: 53, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'}
          ],
   "19219": [
            {id: 1763, data: "blabla", score: 100, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1762, data: "blabla", score: 69, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1761, data: "blabla", score: 32, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {id: 1760, data: "blabla", score: 58, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'}
          ]
 }
```

##### Expected output :

```
 result = [
            {averageScore: 50.24%, date:'2022-08-02T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {averageScore: 57%, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'},
            {averageScore: 64.75%, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'},
          ]
```

Thanks much appreciated !!

Comment: There is invalid syntax for initializing an array. Did you mean an object-like array?

Comment: *"so my loop goes full overflow"*: please provide your code. We don't know what you mean with "my loop".

Comment: @trincot i edit the post like that you can inspire yourself

Comment: Hi @Batuhan i actually i don't know the name of these kind of structure.. When you [ array[ array{ object} ] ] its call object-like ? in that case please confirm or give the correct name and i will change the title thanks :) much appreciated your help

Comment: The loop you have provided is not a *double* loop (that you spoke of), and it does not go "full overflow". Instead it outputs the subarrays. Please update your question to provide code that reproduces the issue you speak of.

Comment: BTW, your input data still has invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi @trincot.. I add some images.. You are right i'm not reaching to represent the structure. i don't know how to do it.. T.T.. could you help me ?

Comment: What is this "will log =>> nothing stack overflow" about? According to the image you included, that is not at all what will be output. Also, there is an answer below. Does it not answer your question?

Comment: i would like to knwo how to represent the structure i'm getting in my logs.. that was my question "18456":  or  "18456"= don't work. 
The question below yes is usefull and i can handle to have what i need.. With all you feedbacks now im courious to know how to represent it.. Do you have any example ??

Comment: @Momo It is not valid syntax also javascript. Arrays doesn't contains keys.They have indexes. If your data comes like given above, It must be an array-like object. So it means an object holds keys and its keys have values that includes an array. I know a little confusing :)

Comment: i changed the info and the title thanks Batuhan real hero here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current data is like below

```js
const arrayLikeObj =
{
  '18456': [
    { id: 1767, data: "blabla", score: 50, date: '2022-08-02T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1766, data: "blabla", score: 70, date: '2022-08-02T12:24:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1765, data: "blabla", score: 68, date: '2022-08-02T12:23:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1764, data: "blabla", score: 13, date: '2022-08-02T12:22:00.000Z' }
  ],
  '19212': [
    { id: 1763, data: "blabla", score: 20, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1762, data: "blabla", score: 75, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1761, data: "blabla", score: 80, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1760, data: "blabla", score: 53, date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z' }
  ],
  '19219': [
    { id: 1763, data: "blabla", score: 100, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1762, data: "blabla", score: 69, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1761, data: "blabla", score: 32, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z' },
    { id: 1760, data: "blabla", score: 58, date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z' }
  ]
};
```

You can use this for getting the desired result.

```js
// Extract only values
const result = Object.values(arrayLikeObj).map(m => {
  return {
    // Iterate over every nested object and get the mean of included scores.
    averageScore: m.reduce((acc, obj) => {
      return acc + obj.score;
    }, 0) / m.length + '%',
    // Get first date of nested object.
    date: m.find(f => f).date
  }
});
```

**Test Section:**

```js
const arrayLikeObj = {
  '18456': [{
      id: 1767,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 50,
      date: '2022-08-02T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1766,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 70,
      date: '2022-08-02T12:24:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1765,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 68,
      date: '2022-08-02T12:23:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1764,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 13,
      date: '2022-08-02T12:22:00.000Z'
    }
  ],
  '19212': [{
      id: 1763,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 20,
      date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1762,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 75,
      date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1761,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 80,
      date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1760,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 53,
      date: '2022-07-15T12:25:00.000Z'
    }
  ],
  '19219': [{
      id: 1763,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 100,
      date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1762,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 69,
      date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1761,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 32,
      date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'
    },
    {
      id: 1760,
      data: "blabla",
      score: 58,
      date: '2022-07-07T12:25:00.000Z'
    }
  ]
};

// Extract only values
const result = Object.values(arrayLikeObj).map(m => {
  return {
    // Iterate over every nested object and get mean of them.
    averageScore: m.reduce((acc, obj) => {
      return acc + obj.score;
    }, 0) / m.length + '%',
    // Get first date of nested object.
    date: m.find(f => f).date
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you help.. I did some changes and my array to an object like that i can use your code

Comment: If it fits, please mark as an answer :)

Comment: I'm checking it but the output of your code is giving me : averageScore + date: { 4 items inside}.. Is there a way in you code to just have averageScore and timestamps only in a single level output? ? 

Thanks already

Comment: @Momo sorry I made a typo. I updated my answer :)

Comment: Wow awesome it works.. Thanks. It really helped my..  i didn't knew Object.values i will keep that in mind ! I i m studing your code and searching on in the internet how it works every steps. Thanks a lot :)